# 'str' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python

В питоне, есть такой код

```
photos = []
ftpConnect.retrlines('NLST', photos.append)
for photo in photos:
    photo = str(photo)
    photo.Replace('thumb_', '')
    photo.Replace('full_', '')
```

Пишет что нет у `photo` такого атрибута как `replace`, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

В Python регистр идентификаторов имеет значение. Поэтому, вы не найдете у строки метода `Replace`, но найдете метод `replace`.

По вашему коду: даже если заменить `Replace` на `replace`, то работать не будет, так как `replace` не изменяет саму строку, а возвращает измененную строку (вообще, строки в Python неизменяемы).

Вызов `photo.replace('thumb_', '')` не повлияет на значение в переменной `photo`. Чтобы значение изменилось, нужно явно записывать туда новое значение:

```
...
photo = photo.replace('thumb_', '')
photo = photo.replace('full_', '')
```